# Jhipster - currently logged in user in Angular Frontend

Tags: angular, authentication, jhipster

How can I get the currently logged in user (more exactly, I need his id) in the frontend of a Jhipster generated application ? The frontend is Angular.

I have seen some older answers using the Principal class, but it seems that doesn't exist anymore.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current authentication state by calling `accountService.getAuthenticationState()`, this will return either `null` if the user is not logged in or an `Account` object otherwise.

Once you have the account you can grab the user login from it and call `userService.find(login)` which will return an object of type `IUser`. At this point you have all the info you need from the current user.

Example (not tested):

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  user!: IUser;

  constructor(
    private accountService: AccountService,
    private userService: UserService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accountService.getAuthenticationState().subscribe(
      account => {
        if (account){
          this.userService.find(account.login).subscribe(
            user => (this.user = user)
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }
...
```